# A list of string tables c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my c# script. I wanted to create a list of string tables as following :

```
public List<string[]> Signals = new List<string[]>(); 
public string[] Communication  =  new string[3];
```

So it's supposed to look like this, I should have several Communication instances in my list : Signals = (Communication1, Communication2, ...) and each Communication has 3 string fields.

When I have gathered my 3 communication datas (different for each communication) :

```
Communication[0]=CommunicationType;
Communication[1]=CommunicationTime;
Communication[2]=CommunicationName;
```

I store them into my list :

```
Signals.Add(Communication); // I have also tried .Insert with different Indexes
```

When I have done this several times, stocking 6 different Communication tables, I want to finally see each one of my Communication instance, so I do as following :

```
foreach (string[] Signal in Signals)
{
    foreach (string CommunicationUnit in Signal)
    {
        Print(CommunicationUnit);
    }
}
```

And all I can see as output is 6 times the last element entered in the list as following

> ARINC3
>
> 121us
>
> Comm6
>
> ARINC3
>
> 121us
>
> Comm6
>
> ARINC3
>
> 121us
>
> Comm6
>
> ARINC3
>
> 121us
>
> Comm6
>
> ARINC3
>
> 121us
>
> Comm6
>
> ARINC3
>
> 121us
>
> Comm6

When I thought I would see each element of my list which are actually 6 different string tables.

I don't understand what is wrong with my script. I think the mistake is somewhere with the foreach loops.

Comment: Use classes instead of `string[]`.

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me you're re-using the same `Communication` array for all 6, so they all show the last data as they share the same reference.  You'd be better off doing as other suggest and creating a class to model your data structure.

Comment: You are not showing the code that has the problem.  Show the full code where you populate the Signals list with Communication arrays.  When you do that, it will become apparent that you are not creating a new array for each List element.  Rather, you are populating the list with references to the same array over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreating a simple example: (it works when you instantiate a new string array after insert)

```
List<string[]> Signals = new List<string[]>(); 
string[] Communication  =  new string[3];

Communication[0] = "a";
Communication[1] = "b";
Communication[2] = "c";

Signals.Add(Communication);

Communication = new string[3];

Communication[0] = "d";
Communication[1] = "e";
Communication[2] = "f";

Signals.Add(Communication);

foreach (string[] Signal in Signals)
{
    foreach (string CommunicationUnit in Signal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CommunicationUnit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the foreach in the foreach? it could be easier to let the communicationUnit loop in signals right?

Comment: you could also do this `Signals.SelectMany(x => x).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` but i doubt that it makes it easier for him to understand.

Comment: HAHAHAHA XD, but still wondering why make a list<string> and put it in a string[]. I mean you can just loop trough the list<string> and its much easier then 2 loops

Answer (score 2):

You seems to just add 6 time the same Communication object in your list.

If you store an object in a list, you just store a reference to it, not a copy.

then if you add you first communication item to the list, and then modify it and add it again, you'll just have 2 time the same reference to the same object in the memory.

that means, if you update your communication item, you'll just update for all rferences in your list.

you must create a new communication item for each.

```
Signals.Add(new string[3] {
    CommunicationType,
    CommunicationTime,
    CommunicationName
});
Signals.Add(new string[3] {
    CommunicationType2,
    CommunicationTime2,
    CommunicationName2
});
```

or

```
string[] Communication  =  new string[3];
Communication[0]=CommunicationType;
Communication[1]=CommunicationTime;
Communication[2]=CommunicationName;
Signals.Add(Communication);
string[] Communication2  =  new string[3];
Communication2[0]=CommunicationType;
Communication2[1]=CommunicationTime;
Communication2[2]=CommunicationName;
Signals.Add(Communication2);
```

if you use the same object, you'll just overwrite its data.

Comment: this is most likely the case here

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining this to me, but as you are saying, if everytime I overwrite Communication I actually write the same data in all my list, why is it working when i reset Communication after each insert using 

 Communication = new string[3];

?

Comment: because when you use the "new" keyword, it create a new object and then a new reference. but your previous object still in memory because it's still in use by your list.
you just don't have access to it anymore if you use "Communication".

Comment: you can check http://www.dotnetperls.com/new or http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx if you want more informations.

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct: the first 3 output lines is your first table (or Signals.First())

```
ARINC3 <- CommunicationType
121us  <- CommunicationTime
Comm6  <- CommunicationName
```

Just like you entered them in the table. You have 6 tables x 3 lines each, so 18 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Create in your class Signal a property with a list of communications and remove the array of strings.

Than use the list in the Signal class to add the communications.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it easy and clean, dont make it to hard for yourself its hard enough.

I just use 1 foreach loop instead of 2 and dont make multiple lists. I just have the list and go trough it in my foreach

```
List<string[]> Signals = new List<string[]>(); 
    string[] Communication  =  new string[3];

Communication[0] = "a";
Communication[1] = "b";
Communication[2] = "c";

Signals.Add(Communication);
i
foreach (string CommunicationUnit in Signals)
{
    Console.Writeline(CommunicationUnit[i]);

}
```